# Play Video on the Browser

Tags: android, android-intent

I tried to open the video from url with Intent.ACTION_VIEW, and it was successful.
But, the problem is, after the browser appeared for a second and it's automatically minimize and the front is the activity on the apps.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri data = Uri.parse("the url of the video with format .m3u8");
intent.setData(data);
startActivity(intent);
```

I'm expecting exactly the same way when i put the URL into the browser manually, but without minimize the browser when it has already been launched.

Need some flags? grateful for any response and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I bet that the browser is just quitting as a result of an inability to display the content. If you plug in the video url to the browser manually, does it work? What is the filetype of the content you are trying to display?

Comment: Sorry for my lack of details questions. Yup, the browser actually load the content properly. In this case the video format is .m3u8

Comment: I have this issue with .mp4's. Whats bothering me is it only happens on certain phones (happens on Nexus S but not Nexus S 4G)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly setting data type by using `setDataAndType(Uri data, String type)` where mime type is "audio/x-mpegurl" (the full mime type is "audio/x-mpegurl; charset=UTF-8"). You might have some switch statement to check URL user has clicked to force type in case link points to ".m3u8".